# Can't redirect on Tizen emulator

Tags: tizen, tizen-emulator

I use the emulator to run a simple HTML code. I want to redirect to my webpage when I click the `a href` tag. But it does not work (It only works on simulator). What is wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<p style="font-size:36px" style="color:#FFFFFF">
<a href="https://www.google.com.vn/?gws_rd=ssl">HELLO</a>
</p>
</body>
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just add a link clinking on will leave the app (and iframes arent supported , are they? ) , this is not what you want so I think on tizen you need to create an control to lunch a browser at given URL from a webapp ?

I can shared an example if needed pm me

Comment: Thanks you, please send me your example. My email: "naphaluan211092@gmail.com"

Answer (score 1):

need to add the following in the config.xml file to allow any traffic or simply the url you need

```html
  <access origin="*" subdomains="true"/>
```